# Reestablish a session after sessionLost

Tags: session, alljoyn

I have the following scenario. A java program (under linux):

- creates two alljoyn sessions against two different remote objects
- calls methods of those objects based on some logic

After a while and for an unknown reason, one of the two sessions is lost (reason = 5, i.e., ALLJOYN_SESSIONLOST_REASON_OTHER). 
To recover from this situation, I start pinging the remote object and as soon as the ping succeed, I recreate the session.

Is this the best way to recover from a session lost?

Thank you!

Comment: What does the reason=5 mean? Could you elaborate?